# Format html text from database to Laravel with blade

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

In the database a field is saved with html text formatted as for example this:

```
<p>Esto es un <strong>mensaje </strong>de prueba</p>
```

When I show it on the screen in blade, the tags appear and it does not format it.

Does anyone know how to make it format?

I have tried this

```
<p>{{$notification->message}}</p>

{{$notification->message}}
```

Shows:

```
<p>Esto es un <strong>mensaje </strong>de prueba</p>
```

but I would like this:

Esto es un **mensaje** de prueba

Comment: Use `{!! $notification->message !!}` instead of `{{ $notification->message }}`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: realise that this is VERY dangerous - especially so if you allow users to create content.  You are leaving yourself open to XSS attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show unescaped data, use `{!! $$notification->message !!}`

Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data